# Classifying metadata into destructiveChangesPre.xml vs destructiveChangesPost.xml

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, ci, destructivechanges.xml

I understand how both [`destructiveChangesPre.xml` & `destructiveChangesPost.xml`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm) work, but I'm wondering if it's possible to algorithmically classify metadata deletions between the two (theoretically; it doesn't need to be non-trivial to implement).

This question might better be expressed as:

> What is the exhaustive list of conditions in which metadata would need to be deleted in postDeployment VS preDeployment?  Or vise-versa?

I'm working on automation, so "algorithm" style answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: if in your experience this is not possible, please explain why!

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, most of destructive changes can go through post destructive. Pre destructive is only needed when you want to make changes inside your deploy and you have some reference that isn't going to allow it.

For instance, if you want to change some custom field type to another type that isn't allow you will need to delete it and all its references in your pre destructive changes.

I think pre destructive is also useful when you need to deal with flowDefinition metadata when versions don't match between orgs